# Worpress.org forum profile block & any contact Email

Tags: forum

I working on wordpress.org forum now recently generate issue for my forum answer not display to another member.

Reply from moderator:

It seems your posts have been picked up by our spam protection (we go over this list every so often to release posts that are caught by accident etc).

In the case of your post, I do see that you've contacted the users off the forums, which is generally not how support on here is handled when helping individual users (it's slightly different if it's a plugin or theme author who have their own support mechanics in place to make sure users are followed up properly and so on, but for individual users this is not something we allow :) )

so how to remove from block list and contact for wordpress.org moderators.

Answer (score 0):

You can contact the forum moderators using this page. [Contact here](http://lists.automattic.com/mailman/listinfo/wp-forums)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks will keep this advice for future answers.

Comment: hii any one tell me how much time for block.

Comment: What is the url of thread